# What is the purpose of client secret in Oauth when a simple rogue client can steal passwords regardless?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, pkce

*This question has not asked before as the premise is different.*

The Client secret is for the authorization server to verify a user is using the **ACTUAL client** to log into the system; Not a **rogue client** created by a hacker.

**However,** a rogue client does not need to authenticate with the server. If a user supplies his username/password on a rogue client, the hacker has literally **stolen the password**. He can then come to the **ACTUAL client** and login with the credentials.

I know we can employ two factor authentication to prevent this. However, my question is: why go through all the mess of having Client Verification as mentioned in the OAUTH Authorization/PKCE flow if it doesn't really matter for the password stealer?

https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce

Finally, the hacker can employ web scraping strategies to automate data capture from the actual client.

Comment: "The Client secret is for the authorization server to verify a user is using the ACTUAL client to log into the system" --what OAuth flow are you talking about here? AFAIK, client secrets are for "clients" like application servers, not end-user apps for mobile or web. The secret is shared between this "client" and the authorization server, and, as your linked page basically says, it should never be included in the end user's app. Its purpose is to ensure only registered "clients" can obtain tokens on behalf of their end users.

Comment: I know, but really, what good does client authorization do? if a hacker is able to steal password, he can just login and it's game over.

Comment: What game is over? The client secret simply isn't there to prevent unauthorized persons from logging in, so don't get hung up on that threat. The client secret is there for non-repudiation, for the benefit of the resource server. With client secrets in place, the resource server can know exactly what client ( == application server) requested any given token. That way, if the client fails to gatekeep its tokens, to ensure abusive or irresponsible sorts of end-user traffic never reach the resource server, the client's authorization can be revoked. Problem solved -- for the resource server!

Comment: Best answer ever thanks :) can you answer it in question so I can select it as best answer. Would be beneficial for future learning noobs like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client secret simply isn't there to prevent unauthorized persons from logging in, so don't get hung up on that threat. In OAuth flows that use it, the client secret is there for non-repudiation, for the benefit of the resource server. With client secrets in place, the resource server can know exactly what client ( == application server) requested any given token. That way, if the client fails to properly protect its tokens & proxy its users' requests, to ensure abusive or irresponsible sorts of end-user traffic never reach the resource server, then the client can be identified with certainty and its authorization can be revoked. Or it can be temporary rate-limited if it has exceeded the SLA, etc. Problem solved -- for the resource server!